# GRC Throttle Block inclusion causes error

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

[image]

The top Embedded Python Block in this GRC application is the stock block.  The bottom one is a LPF the code for which is below.

Without the Throttle Block the application works.  With the Throttle Block the error `gr::log :ERROR: thread_body_wrapper - ERROR thread[thread-per-block[2]: <block Embedded Python Block 2(3)>]: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (17,) into shape (16,)` is generated.  There is no such problem when the Throttle Block is in the path of the stock block.

I learning GRC and would like to understand why the introduction of the Throttle Block is causing the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""

    h = np.array([0.0397989, -0.0488053, -0.0345932, 0.0659844, 0.0315417, -0.1074744, 
    -0.0299212, 0.3187633, 0.5294118, 0.3187633, -0.0299212, -0.1074744, 0.0315417, 
    0.0659844, -0.0345932, -0.0488053, 0.0397989], dtype=np.float32)

    a = True;

    def __init__(self, example_param=2.0):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Embedded Python Block 2',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.float32],
            out_sig=[np.float32]
        )
        # if an attribute with the same name as a parameter is found,
        # a callback is registered (properties work, too).
        self.example_param = example_param

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        """Convolution of input with LPF coefficients"""
        output_items[0][:] = np.convolve(input_items[0], self.h, 'same')

        return len(output_items[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this won't work – convolution has memory, and your convolver doesn't save that. This makes the numbers that come out of your `blk` to depend on in what kind of "chunks" your input signal is delivered. That's not OK, because GNU Radio can (and will) use different lengths at any time.
**Your algorithm must be written in a way that always yields the same result, no matter how your (infinite or finite) input stream is being partitioned for individual calls to `work`.**

That's basically it – the problem here seems to be that the result of your `np.convolve` call doesn't have the same length as `output_itmes[0]`. Read the [documentation of `numpy.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html); it specifies exactly why and when this happens:

> Mode ‘same’ returns output of length max(M, N). Boundary effects are still visible.

So, if the chunk of samples you've gotten is shorter than `h`, then you're trying to save `len(h)` items in a `len(output_items[0])` sized array, which is too short.

This can *always* happen – as said, GNU Radio needs to "cut" the signal into pieces and hand them to your `work`, and the length of these chunks isn't fixed. Your Throttle just makes it more likely to happen.

So, you first need to *conceptually* solve the fact that this is not proper mathematically (the convolution of a long signal is not the same as a sequence of truncated convolutions of short sub-segments, simple as that). Most likely the answer to this is to just use one of the filter blocks GNU Radio comes with anyway.

Comment: (1 of 3) I am new to GNU Radio and appreciate your help.  I am trying to implement DSP in GNU Radio as a way to learn more about DSP, rather than using a supplied filter block.

The GNU Radio documentation is not clear to me on how chunking is done from the signal source to the Throttle or my Embedded Python Block.  I have looked and cannot find a description of how the chunks come from a source.

I do understand that convolution involves memory.  I originally had the code in my block, viz., `len(input_items[0])`, which yielded a consistent `8,192`.

Comment: (2 of 3) Per your response, I realize I don’t understand how the data “chunks” vector is formatted.

The GNU Radio documentation is not clear to me on how chunking is done from the signal source to the Throttle or my Embedded Python Block.  I have looked and cannot find a description of how the chunks come from a source.

The documentation I have seen discusses how to use GRC’s standard tools, and not very much on how to create the tools.

Comment: (3 of 3) The information on Embedded Python Block and writing C++ blocks makes it clear that user tools are possible.  For example, I was looking for documentation for a dashed connector between blocks and could not find an explanation.

Can you tell me where I can find GNU Radio documentation for 1) How GNU Radio sends data from a source, and generally formats data; and 2) How that data from a signal source is “chunked” or cut into pieces?  I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Again, it is nowhere guaranteed that it's a consisten 8192. And as you can see, it's not. You simply **cannot** influence that. The chunking is done to maximize system throughput (at least in theory) by maximizing concurrency. **Your block cannot change that!** There's no special "formatting" done: you just get one finite-length vector after the other from the infinite stream of samples.

Comment: your (3 of 3) are completely separate questions! Please ask them as new questions on here, not in comments to an  answer. Thank you!